# finale vs lilypond

Tags: support, asking-questions

May ask such a question in the forum? I'm using Finale notation program for fifteen years or more. In the forum I learned about lilypond it's a whole different ball game then Finale. Does it pay to  put in alot sweat, energy, and time to learn lilypond?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is written now, I'd consider it too opinion based to work here. You're pretty much asking "Is it worth it for me to learn LilyPond if I already know how to use Finale?" which depends on what you want to do, how you use Finale now, and what your own preferences on this topic are.

However, with a little bit more objective wording and approach I think a similar question would work. A more objective question I see that would work is "Are there any features in LilyPond or Finale that aren't in the other?". This question brings out the features that one has and one doesn't which will help in deciding if it's worth it or not.

Comment: I'll stay over here you answered my question lilypond is for nicer manuscript printing, I don't print them out I study them. By writing the piece I get more intimate with the music, so I think there's no question.

Comment: Generally things like listing features would also be off-topic. A question about the overall strengths and weaknesses of each might be suitable though.